# django: recursion using post-save signal

Tags: django, recursion, save, signals

Here's the situation:

Let's say I have a model A in django. When I'm saving an object (of class A) I need to save it's fields into all other objects of this class. I mean I need every other A object to be copy of lat saved one.

When I use signals (post-save for example) I get a recursion (objects try to save each other I guess) and my python dies.

I men I expected that using .save() method on the same class in pre/post-save signal would cause a recursion but just don't know how to avoid it.

What do we do?

Comment: Maybe add some code so your situation becomes clearer?

Comment: Won't happen if you use pre_save, as you don't have to call save() yourself, it will happen then « naturally ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save_dupe(self):
        super(YourModel, self).save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        for model in YourModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk):
            model.name = self.name
            # Repeat the above for all your other fields
            model.save_dupe()
```

If you have a lot of fields, you'll probably want to iterate over them when copying them to the other model. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: What happens when the model being saved is the User and AFAIK its not a good idea to subclass it. Lets say I have a post_save function with sender as User and inside that function I want to update the instance. Calling save again will in turn trigger the post_save and the local server stops.

Comment: Better yet instead of `model.save_dupe()` just do `super(YourModel, model).save()`.

Answer (score 8):

[@ShawnFumo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410882/shawnfumo) Disconnecting a signal is dangerous if the same model is saved elsewhere at the same time, don't do that !

[@Aram Dulyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354987/aram-dulyan), your solution works but prevent you from using signals which are so powerful !

If you want to avoid recursion and keep using signals (), a simple way to go is to set an attribute on the current instance to prevent upcoming signals firing.

This can be done using a simple decorator that checks if the given instance has the **'skip_signal'** attribute, and if so prevents the method from being called:

```
from functools import wraps

def skip_signal():
    def _skip_signal(signal_func):
        @wraps(signal_func)
        def _decorator(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            if hasattr(instance, 'skip_signal'):
                return None
            return signal_func(sender, instance, **kwargs)  
        return _decorator
    return _skip_signal
```

We can now use it this way:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
@skip_signal()
def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # you processing
    pass

m = MyModel()
# Here we flag the instance with 'skip_signal'
# and my_model_post_save won't be called
# thanks to our decorator, avoiding any signal recursion
m.skip_signal  = True
m.save()
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: Don't forget to `del skip_signal` after your save.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to handle this is to remove the listener while saving. So:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  ...

def foo_post_save(instance):
  post_save.disconnect(foo_post_save, sender=Foo)
  do_stuff_toSaved_instance(instance)
  instance.save()
  post_save.connect(foo_post_save, sender=Foo)

post_save.connect(foo_post_save, sender=Foo)
```